# Playing instead of streaming M3U files (media playlist) on Android

Tags: music-player

I have Xperia Z3 running on Android 6 (Marshmallow). The phone is rooted and Xposed.

I need a way to play `.m3u` or `.m3u8` files on Android, not streaming them, and I want to be able to shuffle the songs.

Tried "MortPlayer Music", but the interface is terrible and there's no shuffle feature.

Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: "without third party": for that we'd neet to know at least your device and Android version, better also the music player(s) already installed.

Comment: Changed the request: thid party is perfectly allowed. Android is V6, but the player is factory custom from sony. No support.

Answer (score 1):

These apps can play the M3U files:

- [**Poweramp Music Player**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer): A little messy too; Having storage glitches on an i9505 TouchWiz.

  Personal score: 8/10
- [**MortPlayer Music**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.folderplayer): No shuffle, disorganized, ugly interface.

  Personal score: 5/10

Answer (score 0):

M3U and M3U8 aren't playable media files, they are playlist files. Open them in any text editor to see what they tell your media player to access.

Comment: I think the question acknowledges that M3U/M3U8 is a playlist file. However, the problem is that some music player apps just don't recognize/support it. Regarding this answer, I'm curious how opening the file in the text editor achieves something?

Comment: It allows you to see what content is being streamed/played when a media player loads (starts playing) the playlist. If you don't want to stream content then download the source files listed in the playlist.

Comment: Ugh, I'm really sorry, I think [I messed up when editing the question back then](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/188974/revisions). Looks like the original question was asking to play local M3U files, not M3U streams. And I misinterpreted it as playing the M3U playlist instead of streaming it.